# PHP PayPal JSON Decode

Tags: php, json, paypal

I am trying to decode this JSON Code to display the Sale Id (5VR4XXXXX4437941)

```
{ "id": "PAY-HIDDEN", "create_time": "2015-05-04T06:30:46Z", "update_time": "2015-05-04T06:32:16Z", "state": "approved", "intent": "sale", "payer": { "payment_method": "paypal", "status": "VERIFIED", "payer_info": { "email": "haroonbg@googlemail.com", "first_name": "XXXXXXX", "last_name": "XXXXXX", "payer_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX", "shipping_address": { "line1": "XXXX", "city": "XXX", "state": "XXX", "postal_code": "XXXTF", "country_code": "GB", "recipient_name": "TXXXXXg" } } }, "transactions": [ { "amount": { "total": "3.00", "currency": "GBP", "details": { "subtotal": "3.00" } }, "description": "uPlayEve 10,000 Coins and 20,000 uPoints", "related_resources": [ { "sale": { "id": "5VR4XXXXX4437941", "create_time": "2015-05-04T06:30:46Z", "update_time": "2015-05-04T06:32:16Z", "amount": { "total": "3.00", "currency": "GBP" }, "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER", "state": "denied", "protection_eligibility": "INELIGIBLE", "parent_payment": "PAY-XXXXXXX", "links": [ { "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/XXXXX", "rel": "self", "method": "GET" }, { "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/XXXXXXXX/refund", "rel": "refund", "method": "POST" }, { "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX", "rel": "parent_payment", "method": "GET" } ] } } ] } ], "links": [ { "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX", "rel": "self", "method": "GET" } ] }
```

Please help I am trying to place the Transaction->sale->id value in a string $saleid

Much appreciated

Haroon

Comment: `$foo = json_decode($your_json); var_dump($foo)`, then follow the path down the rabbit hole.

Comment: No, I mean I need to get the Sale Id as a string so in the JSON  I need to have (transactions->0->related_resources->0->sale->id

Comment: yes, and my code snippet dumps out the information you need to figure out that path.

Comment: I've tried that but all it returns is null I've been trying for 2 days. I've been looking so much online but haven't found anything